# Use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_addss'

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, clang, ros, ninja

I am using CMake to build my ROS project with the following command in VSCode:

```
catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON --use-ninja
```

And using clang for 'Go to Definition', etc, with the following settings:

```
    "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Disabled",
    "clangd.arguments": [
        "--compile-commands-dir=${workspaceFolder}/build",
        "--query-driver=/usr/bin/clang,/usr/bin/c++",
        "--header-insertion=never"
    ],
```

There is no error after executing the command. But in one of the .h files, there is this error hint:

```
In included file: definition of builtin function '_mm_getcsr'clang(builtin_definition)
xmmintrin.h(821, 1): Error occurred here
```

And there are more errors in the xmmintrin.h:

```
[{
    "resource": "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/xmmintrin.h",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "fatal_too_many_errors",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Too many errors emitted, stopping now",
    "source": "clang",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 1
},{
    "resource": "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/xmmintrin.h",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "undeclared_var_use",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_addss'",
    "source": "clang",
    "startLineNumber": 130,
    "startColumn": 19,
    "endLineNumber": 130,
    "endColumn": 39
},{
    "resource": "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/xmmintrin.h",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "undeclared_var_use",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_subss'",
    "source": "clang",
    "startLineNumber": 136,
    "startColumn": 19,
    "endLineNumber": 136,
    "endColumn": 39
},{
    "resource": "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/xmmintrin.h",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "undeclared_var_use",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_mulss'",
    "source": "clang",
    "startLineNumber": 142,
    "startColumn": 19,
    "endLineNumber": 142,
    "endColumn": 39
},{
    "resource": "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/xmmintrin.h",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "undeclared_var_use_suggest",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_divss'; did you mean '__builtin_ia32_minss'? (fix available)",
    "source": "clang",
    "startLineNumber": 148,
    "startColumn": 19,
    "endLineNumber": 148,
    "endColumn": 39,
    "relatedInformation": [
        {
            "startLineNumber": 142,
            "startColumn": 19,
            "endLineNumber": 142,
            "endColumn": 39,
            "message": "'__builtin_ia32_minss' declared here",
            "resource": "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/xmmintrin.h"
        }
    ]
},{
    "resource": "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/xmmintrin.h",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "undeclared_var_use_suggest",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_andps'; did you mean '__builtin_ia32_haddps'? (fix available)",
    "source": "clang",
    "startLineNumber": 242,
    "startColumn": 10,
    "endLineNumber": 242,
    "endColumn": 30,
    "relatedInformation": [
        {
            "startLineNumber": 242,
            "startColumn": 10,
            "endLineNumber": 242,
            "endColumn": 30,
            "message": "'__builtin_ia32_haddps' declared here",
            "resource": "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/xmmintrin.h"
        }
    ]
},{
    "resource": "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/xmmintrin.h",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "undeclared_var_use",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_andnps'",
    "source": "clang",
    "startLineNumber": 248,
    "startColumn": 10,
    "endLineNumber": 248,
    "endColumn": 31
},{
    "resource": "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/xmmintrin.h",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "undeclared_var_use",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_orps'",
    "source": "clang",
    "startLineNumber": 254,
    "startColumn": 10,
    "endLineNumber": 254,
    "endColumn": 29
},{
    "resource": "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/xmmintrin.h",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "undeclared_var_use",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_xorps'",
    "source": "clang",
    "startLineNumber": 260,
    "startColumn": 10,
    "endLineNumber": 260,
    "endColumn": 30
},{
    "resource": "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/xmmintrin.h",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "undeclared_var_use",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_movss'",
    "source": "clang",
    "startLineNumber": 288,
    "startColumn": 19,
    "endLineNumber": 288,
    "endColumn": 39
},{
    "resource": "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/xmmintrin.h",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "undeclared_var_use",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_movss'",
    "source": "clang",
    "startLineNumber": 298,
    "startColumn": 19,
    "endLineNumber": 298,
    "endColumn": 39
},{
    "resource": "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/xmmintrin.h",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "undeclared_var_use",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_movss'",
    "source": "clang",
    "startLineNumber": 326,
    "startColumn": 19,
    "endLineNumber": 326,
    "endColumn": 39
},{
    "resource": "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/xmmintrin.h",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "undeclared_var_use",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_movss'",
    "source": "clang",
    "startLineNumber": 336,
    "startColumn": 19,
    "endLineNumber": 336,
    "endColumn": 39
},{
    "resource": "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/xmmintrin.h",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "undeclared_var_use_suggest",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_cmpgtps'; did you mean '__builtin_ia32_cmpltps'? (fix available)",
    "source": "clang",
    "startLineNumber": 380,
    "startColumn": 19,
    "endLineNumber": 380,
    "endColumn": 41,
    "relatedInformation": [
        {
            "startLineNumber": 368,
            "startColumn": 19,
            "endLineNumber": 368,
            "endColumn": 41,
            "message": "'__builtin_ia32_cmpltps' declared here",
            "resource": "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/xmmintrin.h"
        }
    ]
},{
    "resource": "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/xmmintrin.h",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "undeclared_var_use_suggest",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_cmpgeps'; did you mean '__builtin_ia32_cmpleps'? (fix available)",
    "source": "clang",
    "startLineNumber": 386,
    "startColumn": 19,
    "endLineNumber": 386,
    "endColumn": 41,
    "relatedInformation": [
        {
            "startLineNumber": 374,
            "startColumn": 19,
            "endLineNumber": 374,
            "endColumn": 41,
            "message": "'__builtin_ia32_cmpleps' declared here",
            "resource": "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/xmmintrin.h"
        }
    ]
},{
    "resource": "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/xmmintrin.h",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "undeclared_var_use_suggest",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_cmpngtps'; did you mean '__builtin_ia32_cmpnltps'? (fix available)",
    "source": "clang",
    "startLineNumber": 410,
    "startColumn": 19,
    "endLineNumber": 410,
    "endColumn": 42,
    "relatedInformation": [
        {
            "startLineNumber": 380,
            "startColumn": 19,
            "endLineNumber": 380,
            "endColumn": 41,
            "message": "'__builtin_ia32_cmpnltps' declared here",
            "resource": "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/xmmintrin.h"
        }
    ]
},{
    "resource": "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/xmmintrin.h",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "undeclared_var_use_suggest",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_cmpngeps'; did you mean '__builtin_ia32_cmpnleps'? (fix available)",
    "source": "clang",
    "startLineNumber": 416,
    "startColumn": 19,
    "endLineNumber": 416,
    "endColumn": 42,
    "relatedInformation": [
        {
            "startLineNumber": 386,
            "startColumn": 19,
            "endLineNumber": 386,
            "endColumn": 41,
            "message": "'__builtin_ia32_cmpnleps' declared here",
            "resource": "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/xmmintrin.h"
        }
    ]
},{
    "resource": "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/xmmintrin.h",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "undeclared_var_use_suggest",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_cvtsi2ss'; did you mean '__builtin_ia32_cvtsd2ss'? (fix available)",
    "source": "clang",
    "startLineNumber": 602,
    "startColumn": 19,
    "endLineNumber": 602,
    "endColumn": 42,
    "relatedInformation": [
        {
            "startLineNumber": 602,
            "startColumn": 19,
            "endLineNumber": 602,
            "endColumn": 42,
            "message": "'__builtin_ia32_cvtsd2ss' declared here",
            "resource": "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/xmmintrin.h"
        }
    ]
},{
    "resource": "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/xmmintrin.h",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "init_conversion_failed",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Cannot initialize a parameter of type '__attribute__((__vector_size__(2 * sizeof(double)))) double' (vector of 2 'double' values) with an lvalue of type 'int'",
    "source": "clang",
    "startLineNumber": 602,
    "startColumn": 58,
    "endLineNumber": 602,
    "endColumn": 61
},{
    "resource": "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/xmmintrin.h",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "undeclared_var_use_suggest",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_cvtsi642ss'; did you mean '__builtin_ia32_cvtsd2ss'? (fix available)",
    "source": "clang",
    "startLineNumber": 618,
    "startColumn": 19,
    "endLineNumber": 618,
    "endColumn": 44,
    "relatedInformation": [
        {
            "startLineNumber": 602,
            "startColumn": 19,
            "endLineNumber": 602,
            "endColumn": 42,
            "message": "'__builtin_ia32_cvtsd2ss' declared here",
            "resource": "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/xmmintrin.h"
        }
    ]
}]
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: I have faced similar errors using HLS vivado high level synthesis for FPGA